# Duplicate task appearing in task list

Tags: task-list

I have created an "action items" list and every time I add a new item it adds to the list and then once you refresh the page it adds a second item below and calls it "action item initiated: task name"

How do I get rid of the duplicate task? I only want it to appear on the list one time.

Comment: This is atypical behavior for a standard SharePoint task list. Is it possible that there is a workflow associated with the task list?

We will need more information to help you further. Please answer the following questions:

- Are you using SharePoint 2007 or 2010?
- What template did you use when you created the list: Tasks? Custom List? Something else?Did you create this list or did someone else create it?

Comment: There are two workflow options available to me: 1) Disposition Approval 2) Three-State. Three-State is the option currently selected. We are using SP 2010. I didn't create the list, but it does appear to be a task list.